# Loading data with WebClient on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to load data from web-page using WebClient. Here is part of my code

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(titleUri));
```

The problem is that if I perform my application in debugger string-by-string everything is working fine, but if I just deploy and run application on WP Emulator the data from page isn't loaded. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: is your phone able to access the internet network?

Comment: Yes. I'm testing all this code on WP emulator. The track is the stream from the internet(and I can hear it clearly), and my main target is to update track title from the stream.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Or just empty string? Or null?

Comment: I'm getting a web exception. As I have told in question if I run programm string-by-string everything works fine, but if I just run the programm it doesn't work as intended. I've spoken to one of my friends and he said that this can be due to multi-thread work of the programm(this part of code is in BackgroundAudioTask).